# IE8 Shadow filter on input offsets cursor

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, shadow

The `DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow` filter moves the visual presentation of the input but the cursor is left in its original place.

The CSS:

```
input {
    filter:
      progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#cccccc,direction=0,strength=50),
      progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#cccccc,direction=45,strength=2),
      progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#cccccc,direction=90,strength=5),
      progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#cccccc,direction=135,strength=2),
      progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#cccccc,direction=180,strength=5),
      progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#cccccc,direction=225,strength=2),
      progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#cccccc,direction=270,strength=5),
      progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#cccccc,direction=315,strength=2);
}
```

Demo Page: http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/Pzqtd/

If you open it in IE8 or IE9 you'll see that the cursor of the input is 50px above the input.

So any ideas how to fix it or may be other solutions to create shadow for input in IE8?

I need the shadow for IE8 specifically - I cannot use `box-shadow`

Comment: it's not the solution but you can omit filter for IE9

Comment: @Vladimir Starkov: I can, but it won't fix behaviour for ie8 ;-)

Comment: But it reduce the problem in IE9

Comment: @Vladimir Starkov: the question is about ie8 :-) That's why it has only IE8 in the title and tags. I mentioned Ie9 here just for a demonstration

Comment: Even IE can't handle their made-up filters...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sort of a hack but worked for me. You might need to tweak it a bit. http://jsfiddle.net/subash1232/DDUvP/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="shadow">
</div>

<input type="text" value="value" />
```

**CSS**

```
input {
   border: 1px solid red;
   position: relative;
   width: 178px;
   top: 34px;
   left:9px;
   z-index: 1000;
}

.shadow{
   height: 20px;
   width: 180px;
   background: white;
   filter:  
     progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#cccccc,direction=0,strength=50),
     progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#cccccc,direction=45,strength=2),
     progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#cccccc,direction=90,strength=5),
     progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#cccccc,direction=135,strength=2),
     progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#cccccc,direction=180,strength=5),
     progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#cccccc,direction=225,strength=2),
     progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#cccccc,direction=270,strength=5),
     progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(color=#cccccc,direction=315,strength=2);

}
```